# Python Unittests OOM?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I currently have multiple Python unit tests that work perfectly when run separately. Unfortunately, when running together, their memory consumption adds up resulting in an Out Of Memory problem or a super slow run time at best.

My code for running the tests looks like this:

```
loader = unittest.TestLoader()
suite = unittest.TestSuite()

suite.addTests(loader.loadTestsFromModule(TestRemoveValues()))
# Adding several tests.
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2)
runner.run(suite)
```

I am thinking of creating separate runners for separate tests in order to free memory between tests but it does not seem elegant and I am not sure it will work.

Any ideas on how to clean up memory after each test?

Comment: Show, please, example of unittests.

Comment: I suspect that it's the SUT code that uses a lot of memory, not the tests. Try the use of generators, instead of loading all your data at once.